# How do you apply a catalog price rule to a limited quantity?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I have setup a catalog price rule applied to all my products but wanted to limit to a maximum quantity that can be applied then it will revert back to the 'full' price.

Comment: Always mention proper magento version.

Answer (score 1):

Since quantity is not available to be used Catalog Rules therefore this won't be possible straight. But there can be a custom field that can hold your quantity (or the maximum quantity) and thus can be used to create catalog rule to achieve the goal.

Comment: What do you mean the custom field, could you please post detailed about that.